# Stored Procedure slower than query in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**UPDATE:** I have solved the problem, refer to solution below.

My stored procedure is slower than the SQL query. Both are executed in SSMS directly in the test. I need feedback why and how to solve. I can see that the queries are using different non-clustered index in the DB and I'm not sure why.

**Stored procedure:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 25 
[data_unit_id], [creation_date], [name], [parent_data_unit_id], [data_unit_identity_unique_name], [receiving_flow_status], [sending_flow_status], [target_connector], [closed], [nummer], [date], [receiver_endpoint], [receiver_name], [reference_document_id], [sender_endpoint], [sender_id], [sender_name], [receiver_email], [creditnote_total], [tax_number], [order_reference], [type], [responce_text] 
 FROM metadata 
 WHERE 
   (  (  creation_date >= @1 )  AND  (  closed = @2 AND  nummer LIKE @3 )  AND  creation_date <= @4 AND  creation_date >= @5 )  
 ORDER BY [creation_date] DESC 

',N'@1 bigint,@2 nvarchar(5),@3 nvarchar(4),@4 bigint,@5 bigint',@1=130288572000000000,@2=N'False',@3=N'%156',@4=130295155780753712,@5=130289107780753712
```

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT TOP 25 
     [data_unit_id], [creation_date], [name], [parent_data_unit_id],   
     [data_unit_identity_unique_name], [receiving_flow_status], [sending_flow_status], 
     [target_connector], [closed], [nummer], [date], [receiver_endpoint], [receiver_name], 
     [reference_document_id], [sender_endpoint], [sender_id], [sender_name], [receiver_email], 
     [creditnote_total], [tax_number], [order_reference], [type], [responce_text] 
FROM metadata 
WHERE 
   ((creation_date >= 130288572000000000)
    AND (closed = 'False' AND nummer LIKE '%156')  
    AND creation_date <= 130295155780753712 
    AND creation_date >= 130289107780753712 
   )  
ORDER BY 
   [creation_date] DESC
```

**UPDATE**:
If I change @3=N'%678' to @3=N'%78' and the datatype size for this variable to nvarchar(3) the search goes from >30 s to 200ms. The datatype of nummer in the DB is nvarchar(300). This is the SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 25 
    [data_unit_id], [creation_date], [name], [parent_data_unit_id], [data_unit_identity_unique_name], [receiving_flow_status], [sending_flow_status], [target_connector], [closed], [nummer], [date], [receiver_endpoint], [receiver_name], [reference_document_id], [sender_endpoint], [sender_id], [sender_name], [receiver_email], [creditnote_total], [tax_number], [order_reference], [type], [responce_text] 
     FROM metadata 
     WHERE 
       (  (  creation_date >= @1 )  AND  (  closed = @2 AND  nummer LIKE @3 )  AND  creation_date <= @4 AND  creation_date >= @5 )  
     ORDER BY [creation_date] DESC 

    ',N'@1 bigint,@2 nvarchar(5),@3 nvarchar(3),@4 bigint,@5 bigint',@1=130288572000000000,@2=N'False',@3=N'%56',@4=130295155780753712,@5=130289107780753712
```

**Solution:**
It was problems with similiar/conflicting indexes and the solution was to drop one of them. How I solved it: 
With the SQL query in SSMS have a look at the Execution plan and which index object is used. Is it the same for the slow SP?
If they use different indexes try to use the fast one in SP. Example how force use of specific index:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable WITH (INDEX(IndexName))
WHERE MyIndexedColumn = 0
```

Comment: how much slower? did you look at the execution plans? post them. That should get some light into the issue.

Comment: You SP is dynamic sql ?

Comment: Duration of SP is 32 seconds and sql some milliseconds.

Comment: I will provide executions plans in a few minutes, thanks!

Comment: SP execution plan in XML(other format?):

Comment: Should not matter, but since you're asking I would always prefer the graphic display of the actual execution plans ;); if you cannot embed them into your post just upload to imgur or sth and link it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
It was problems with similiar/conflicting indexes and the solution was to drop one of them. How I solved it: 
With the SQL query in SSMS have a look at the Execution plan and which index object is used. Is it the same for the slow SP?
If they use different indexes try to use the fast one in SP. Example how force use of specific index:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable WITH (INDEX(IndexName))
WHERE MyIndexedColumn = 0
```

Comment: Using specific index saved many hours and my mind, thanks a lot! It really works.

Comment: This was my case as well. Tons of info about "parameter sniffing" and recompilation and just one post about hitting the wrong index.

Answer (score 3):

SQL can have a problem often referred to as Parameter sniffing. One solution to this is to declare variables within the procedure and assign the parameters to them: (I don't know why this works, but I have had some success with this method in the past).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SprocName]
@Parameter1     DATETIME,
@Parameter2         VARCHAR(30), .......

DECLARE @1 DATETIME
SET @1 = @Parameter1

DECLARE @2 VARCHAR(30)
SET @2 = @Parameter2
```

another is to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of your query.

However, these don't work in all instances. If they don't work then you will be best to look at your execution plans and optimise your sproc.

---

here is a good read around parameter sniffing.

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: The answer is useful, but this was not the problem. I believe many developeres have the same issue as me. Please have a look at the solution in my original post, thanks!